# How to pass a script to a functional component

Tags: reactjs

How to pass a script to a functional component. I want to show a payment button in an application made in react.

The script take it from the following link:
https://docs.livepayphone.com/knowledge-base/expresscheckout/?unapproved=1933&moderation-hash=3284f081dabdbc0412309ac9236d38cf#comment-1933

The script is as follows:

```
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      payphone.Button({
         token: TOKEN,
         btnHorizontal: true,
         btnCard: true,
         createOrder: function(actions){
            return actions.prepare({
               amount: 100,
               amountWithoutTax: 100,
               currency: "USD",
               clientTransactionId: ID_TRANSACTION
            });
         },
         onComplete: function(model, actions){
            actions.confirm({
               id: model.id,
               clientTxId: model.clientTxId
            }).then(function(value){
               console.log(VALUE);
            }).catch(function(err){
               console.log(err);
            });
         }
      }).render(‘#pp-button’);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the script at the bottom of the **body** of your **public/index.html** without the **render** function.

Something like this:

```
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      payphone.Button({
        token: TOKEN,
        btnHorizontal: true,
        btnCard: true,
        createOrder: function (actions) {
          return actions.prepare({
            amount: 100,
            amountWithoutTax: 100,
            currency: "USD",
            clientTransactionId: ID_TRANSACTION
          });
        },
        onComplete: function (model, actions) {
          actions.confirm({
            id: model.id,
            clientTxId: model.clientTxId
          }).then(function (value) {
            console.log(VALUE);
          }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Make sure you also added the cdn in the **head** the public/index.html

```
 <script src=»https://pay.payphonetodoesposible.com/api/button/js?appId=ACATUIDDEAPLICACION»></script>
```

Then create a button anywhere on your react app with the **id: pp-button**

```
<button id="pp-button">Button</button>
```

Comment: how to pass as parameters amount and amountWithoutTax ?

Comment: How would the payment button be rendered if the id is not set?